# Can MassTransit be configured to use the HTTPS REST endpoints of Azure service bus?

Tags: azureservicebus, masstransit

I have configured Mass Transit to send messages to Azure Service Bus via AMQP, but have now discovered that the ports will be blocked in our production environment.

Unblocking these ports is not going to be an option in the short term, so can I configure Mass Transit to use the Azure Service Bus REST endpoints instead? I know that HTTPS will not be blocked.

Comment: I have come across this fork https://github.com/drusellers/MassTransit/tree/http which implies to me, that it is not supported by default

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use the REST endpoints, instead of AMQP, you can change the configuration of Azure Service Bus in the host.

```
x.Host(serviceUri, h =>
{
    ...
    h.TransportType = TransportType.NetMessaging;
});
```

This will use the REST endpoint, but you need to also configure the service bus environment for the process:

```
ServiceBusEnvironment.SystemConnectivity.Mode = ConnectivityMode.Https;
```

This will tell the client libraries for Azure to use HTTPS (you can also specify HTTP if you like).

Comment: You're my new hero. I thought I was going to have to throw away Mass Transit because of this. Thank you.

Comment: Chris,                                                                                                                                                     What do you mean by REST endpoint?  I get the error in brlow link. Does it mean its using REST endpoint. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7eff7b84-6833-4a0c-8bcd-715d6a4db4ac/unable-to-find-an-entry-point-named-getperadapterinfo-in-dll-iphlpapidll?forum=azureautomation